# How to display AddToAny social links and "Continue reading" side-by-side in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display my [social media plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-to-any/)'s links and "Continue reading -->" side-by-side in my WordPress posts.

I am using the WordPress `<!--more-->` tag to add the "Continue reading" link.

Here is what I am getting at the moment:
[image: What i am getting in posts]

And here is how I want it to look:
[image: What i want]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific CSS for this is going to be different for every plugin, so here's a solution specific to [AddToAny](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-to-any/), the plugin you're using:

```
.more-link { float: right; margin: 16px 0px 16px 0px; }
.addtoany_share_save_container { float: left; clear: none; margin: 0px 0px 16px 0px; }
```

This should 'float' the 'more' link to the right, and the social links to the left. It also adds some space above/below the more link, and removes both the 'float clearer' and the space the plugin adds, to hopefully bring it into line.

Depending on your theme and layout, you might need to adjust the margins to make it fit. Each of the above margin sizes are expressed in order as top-right-bottom-left, so you should be able to adjust just the numbers you need to to make it right.

As for where to add this code, in your WordPress admin under Appearance, there should, hopefully, be an option saying 'Edit CSS' (it depends on your theme). Click that option, then you can add the above CSS code to the box provided. If your theme doesn't have that option, it looks you can add it instead to the 'Additional CSS' option within the AddToAny page under Settings.

I've tested this on my blog and it looks like this, which I believe is what you wanted:

[image]

Comment: thank you sir . its working fine for me. sir could you suggest me a code which can work with all social media share plugins ?

Comment: @Arpitgupta In regards to all social media share plugins, that's impossible. Every plugin is going to name their CSS classes differently, so every solution like this will need to be tailored. You can, however, right click on the social icons in your browser and open the 'inspect element' tool, which will let you see the CSS classes that a particular plugin assigns. You can then modify the CSS to target another plugin's class rather than `addtoany_share_save_container`.

Comment: sir , could you suggest me a tutorial site from where i can learn wordpress completely. ?

Comment: @Arpitgupta You probably need to Google around for the right one, but [here's a list of tutorials I found that looks good](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/wordpress-tutorials-designers-1012990).